# Segfault when using fread()

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, fread

I get a segmentation fault when calling `fread()` and I just can't figure out where the error might be:

```
`void charger(Repertoire* parent){
    int i;
    if (parent == 0){parent = &source;}
    FILE* rep_file = fopen("repertoires.bin", "rb");
    fread(parent, sizeof(Repertoire), 1, rep_file); //<-------------- here
    fclose(rep_file);
    //more code...`
```

For reference, my function `charger()` is called here:

```
`int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int i, j, path = 0;
    source.nom = "/.";
    disque = (char*) calloc(32000, sizeof(char));
    charger(0);
    //more code...`
```

And Repertoire is defined here in a header file (builder is initialized in the .c file):

```
`typedef struct repertoire{
    int taille;
    int itaille;
    char* nom;
    struct repertoire* enfants;
    int countup;
    int icountup;
    struct inode* fichiers;
} Repertoire;
Repertoire source;
//more code...`
```

Anybody can help?

Comment: You only produce a few snippets of code, but the error occurs when reading a file, when you did not check that the file has actually been opened. Test the return value from `fopen` always: it is a fundamental necessity. And please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Ahhh it seems I was making an improper use of fopen then. I thought I could create a file using fopen with the read option. This solves my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to use fread on a file that did not exist, which triggered a segmentation fault. I thought fopen (with the read option) allowed me to create a file, but this can only be done with write and append.